# Running async Kotlin code with dispatchers

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to wrap my head around async code execution with Kotlin coroutines.

Why do I have to specify a dispatcher when launching asynchronous code blocks?

The following code block

```
fun doInParallel(): Unit = runBlocking {
    coroutineScope {
        launch { println("start A").also { Thread.sleep(1_000) }.also { println("finish A") } }
        launch { println("start B").also { Thread.sleep(1_000) }.also { println("finish B") } }
    }
}
```

will always print

```
start A
finish A
start B
finish B
```

which is not what I expected.

Only after explicitly specifying a dispatcher the async code blocks run in parallel:

```
fun doInParallel(): Unit = runBlocking {
    coroutineScope {
        launch(Dispatchers.Default) { println("start A").also { Thread.sleep(1_000) }.also { println("finish A") } }
        launch(Dispatchers.Default) { println("start B").also { Thread.sleep(1_000) }.also { println("finish B") } }
    }
}
```

will print

```
start A
start B
finish A
finish B
```

Why do I have to include `Dispatcher.Default`?

I'm using `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.0-Beta` (if that is of any relevance)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Coroutines Should Suspend, Not Block

Instead of `Thread.sleep(...)`, use `delay(...)`.

`Thread.sleep` blocks the thread, and with coroutines the idea is that you want to *suspend* the thread, not block it. When a thread is suspended from one coroutine using a suspend function like `delay`, that same thread is free to go service another coroutine -- in this case the one started by the second `launch`.

The reason specifying the dispatcher in your second example has different behavior is that `coroutineScope` inherits the coroutine context from the parent scope, which in this case is `runBlocking`. The default dispatcher in the `runBlocking` coroutine builder is documented:

> The default CoroutineDispatcher for this builder is an internal implementation of event loop that processes continuations in this blocked thread until the completion of this coroutine.

In other words, in your example, everything is running inside a single thread: the main thread (or whatever thread is calling `doInParallel`). That in combination with using the blocking `Thread.sleep` means the code is executing in a blocking manner and synchronously.

To summarize:

1. Change your code to print the thread name, and you'll see everything runs in the `main` thread (unless you specify the dispatcher).
2. Change from using `Thread.sleep` to `delay` to fix the underlying problem, and allow a single thread to run both launched coroutines.

```kotlin
fun doInParallel(): Unit = runBlocking {
  coroutineScope {
    launch { println("${Thread.currentThread().name} start A").also { delay(1_000) }.also { println("${Thread.currentThread().name} finish A") } }
    launch { println("${Thread.currentThread().name} start B").also { delay(1_000) }.also { println("${Thread.currentThread().name} finish B") } }
  }
}
```

### How to run blocking code?

To run blocking code inside a coroutine, use [`Dispatchers.IO`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html), which is explicitly designed for offloading blocking tasks to a shared pool of threads. Additionally, as per the comment by @George Leung, the [`runInterruptible`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-interruptible.html) method can be used to call the specified block in an interruptible manner, if the underlying code is responsive to thread interrupts.

Comment: So coroutines in Kotlin can't be interrupted and single coroutines are prone to starvation, if other's don't play nicely, right?

Comment: They don't use the Java thread interruption mechanism, and yes.

Comment: On your second question, yes, absolutely. Though you can run blocking code inside a dispatcher designed for it, such as `Dispatchers.IO`.

Comment: If you have blocking code that can be interrupted, you can use [`runInterruptible(Dispatchers.IO)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-interruptible.html). That will translate a coroutine cancel to a thread interrupt.