# Kotlin Coroutine equivalent way as @Async in Spring Java

Tags: spring, kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines

Spring provides a way to support asynchronous execution with annotation of `@Async` and `@EnableAsync`, in the below code as Java, my API won't be blocked and can respond without waiting for the expensive operation to be finished.

```
@Post
public Response saveUserDetail(UserDetail userDetail) {
   System.out.println("saveUserDetail Started...");
   // very expensive operation
   userRepo.save(userDetail);
   System.out.println("saveUserDetail Completed...");
}

@Async
public void save(UserDetail userDetail) {
   // took 30s
   Thread.sleep(30000);
}
```

Now Kotlin has a coroutine package to write an async process in a sync way, however, what'd be the Kotlin way to achieve the above behaviour without using `@Async`? I've tried `suspend` and `async` but they seem will still block my request thread that I cannot get my API response without waiting in expensive operation

Comment: It looks like you should use `launch` instead of `async`. But if you don't do extra operations, such as `join()` or `await()`, it will not block the  coroutine. Can you post your `Kotlin` code?

Comment: In your coroutines code, are you testing your "expensive operation" with a `Thread.sleep`? If so, that would be your problem -- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76009163/430128.

Comment: @Raman yes I am, but with `Spring Async` it's working as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin coroutines are not the same as regular Java threads. Coroutines have two properties that are different than threads which I believe are relevant to you:

1. Coroutines use [structured concurrency](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#structured-concurrency). An outer coroutine scope will not complete until all child coroutines are complete.
2. Coroutines should not be blocked by calls such as `Thread.sleep()` unless care is taken to run such blocking code in a dispatcher designed for it, such as `Dispatchers.IO`. Instead, use a suspending call like `delay()` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76009163/430128 for details about this.

Now in your case, it appears you want `saveUserDetail` to complete without waiting for `save` to finish. Keep in mind this Spring code isn't safe, because if `saveUserDetail` throws an error, the client will never know about it. Or if `saveUserDetail` never returns for some reason, the thread will leak. Structured concurrency in Kotlin is intended to prevent such unsafe code by default. With coroutines and structured concurrency, the response will not return until the `saveUserDetail` call finishes, and it doesn't matter if the `async` or `launch` coroutine builders are used or not, because by default they simply start a child coroutine. The parent *still* won't complete until the child coroutine started by `async` or `launch` is done.

If you *really* want the unsafe version of this code, you need to launch the coroutine into a different coroutine scope *that is not a child of the request scope*, such as the [`GlobalScope`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/). For example:

```kotlin
GlobalScope.launch {
  userRepo.save(userDetail);
}
```

Make sure you read all the caveats of using `GlobalScope` in the docs.

You can also create your own background scope and use that. Example:

```kotlin
val backgroundOpsScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())
...
suspend fun saveUserDetail(userDetail: UserDetail) {
  backgroundOpsScope.launch {
    ... expensive operation ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much and it was awesome to learn from it!